# What is the fallacy Carl Jung is alluding to in this passage?

Tags: fallacies, psychology, syllogism

What kind of fallacy did he mean?

> *We  start,  for instance  with  a  perfectly  reasonable  assumption,
>
> such  as "NO UNREASONABLE BEING IS FREE" - in other words, has  free  will.
>
> This is  an  example  which  is used  in  logic.  It  is a  fairly reasonable  statement.  Now we come to  the first  fallacy,  "THEREFORE, NO FREE BEING IS UNREASONABLE."  You cannot quite agree because there  is already a  trick.
> Then you continue, "All human beings are free" - they  all have  free will.
> Now  you  triumphantly  finish up, "Therefore no human being is unreasonable."
> That is  complete nonsense.*

Comment: Not clear; the inference from "No being is Unreasonable and Free" to "No being is Free and Unreasonable" is sound. Maybe he means that the "move" from "Unreasonable Being" to "being Unreasonable" hides a difference in meaning...

Comment: Seems like a false binary or false dilemma, informal fallacy. The implication is, reasonable or unreasonable only, no degrees of. & so, free or unfree, only. But the basis of the statements in bold, is we are free in so far as we can reason our choices, not be coerced, eg by instinct/compulsion, or choices made by others. So it amounts to a tautology: if being free is reasoning our choices, reasoning our choices is being free

Comment: Even if free will is assumed, an unreasonable person may be more free than a reasonable one, as reason manifests as a form of constraint.

Comment: Judging by context, this is a case of a "bad example". In the lecture Jung describes Freud's theory of dreams as "complete distortions" of the "original figure" by faulty logic, and this example is supposed to illustrate the faulty logic. He seems to not have noticed that the logic is not actually faulty. Perhaps he misremembered "an example which is used in logic" (something like affirming the consequent) and did not give it much thought because, superficially, the conclusion sounds more suspect than the premise due to habitual shifts in the meanings of "free" and "unreasonable".

Comment: Following the answer below, see [Reductio](https://www.britannica.com/topic/reduction-logic): a perfectly correct syllogistic inference: from "No A is B" to "No B is A"; in this way, the second figure can be "reduced to" the fist figure. In conclusion, Jung is simply misunderstanding the rules of Syllogistic, whatever Freud's original statement may be.

Comment: The Syllogism is: "Every Human is Free; Every Free being is Reasonable (not-Unreasonable). Therefore: Every Human is Reasonable." It is formally valid; the issue is: is the conclusion true? It depends on the truth/falsity of the premises.

Answer (score 1):

I found this quote interesting, so I looked it up. It appears in in the *[Collected Works of C.G Jung, Volume 18: The Symbolic Life: Miscellaneous Writings](https://books.google.ca/books?id=1BQ3AgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)*.

Jung gives this example to illustrate what he calls *reductio in primam figuram*, which he claims is a logical device used by Freud. He explains this in the passage that precedes the one in the post:

> Freud applies the method of free association and makes use of an entirely different logical principle, a principle which in logic is called *reductio in primam figuram*, a reduction to the first figure. The *reductio in primam figuram* is a so-called syllogism, a complicated sequence of logical conclusions, whose characteristic is that you start from a perfectly reasonable statement, and, through surreptitious assumptions and insinuations, you gradually change the reasonable nature of your first simple or prime figure until you reach a complete distortion which is utterly unreasonable. (p. 84)

How does Jung's example illustrate this principle? Here is the example again:

1. No unreasonable being is free (assumption)
2. No free being is unreasonable (from 1)
3. All human beings are free (assumption)
4. Therefore, no human being is unreasonable (from 2,3)

Unfortunately, it does not seem to. I take it that the conclusion is supposed to be "complete nonsense" because obviously some people are sometimes unreasonable, in the sense that they do/believe/want things without good reasons. But then the first assumption is  obviously false as well, so we don't have here a chain of reasoning that "starts from a perfectly reasonable statement". On the other hand, the first assumption may be acceptable if by "unreasonable" we mean "incapable of reason". But then the conclusion is acceptable as well.

Jung may have thought that the move from 1 to 2 is a fallacy. He says in the quote in the post "Now we come to the first fallacy" just before he introduces 2. But it is in fact a valid logical inference of the form "No A is B; therefore, No B is A". The inference from 2,3 to 4 is valid as well.

It is possible, however, that he thought that there was a fallacy of equivocation here, with the two senses of "unreasonable" I mentioned above. Also, this is a translated text, so it is possible something has been lost in translation.

Comment: Jung does not say that what the quote describes is a device used by Freud, he says that it is a device used by dreams *according* to Freud:"*That complete distortion, in Freud ’s idea, characterizes the dream; the dream is a clever distortion that disguises the original figure, and you have only to undo the web in order to return to the first reasonable statement*". Your quote is very confusing in isolation because, as the subsequent text makes clear, *reductio in primam figuram* is the *undoing* of what is described in the quote, and that undoing is the device he ascribes to Freud.

Comment: +1 Good point...

Answer (score 0):

The fallacy in question is a relative of the classic syllogistic [Four Terms Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_four_terms). The four terms fallacy occurs when we use a term with multiple senses, and subtly (or unsubtly) shift from one sense to another midstream.  My favorite example is:

- P1: Nothing is better than complete happiness
- P2: A ham sandwich is better than nothing
- C: A ham sandwich is better than complete happiness

in which the term 'nothing' has entirely different connotations in P1 and P2.

In Jung's case we have the following syllogistic structure

- P1(a): No unreasonable being is free

  - P1(b): No free being is unreasonable (logical converse of P1a)
- P2: All human beings are free
- C: No human being is unreasonable

From Jung's perspective — and the perspective of many, many others) — P1(a/b) is a perfectly good assumption. Psychology and Liberal philosophy both hold that (psychological) freedom means the capacity for rational thought and action. 'Unreasoning' behavior is a sign of mental defect — ignorance, emotional disorder, obsession, neurosis, psychosis — and mental defects constrain human behavior, preventing us from appreciating or engaging in the full range of human activities. However, P2 invokes a different (philosophical) sense off the term freedom: freedom as an abstract form of 'free will' entrenched in Liberal ideals. That shift in the sense of the term 'freedom' creates the strange-seeming conclusion.